# Can I stop WCF hanging at 100% CPU by making it time out?

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

We have a problem with our WCF service, whereby if the user searches for something silly like 'a a a a a' then the WCF service ends up doing an insane operation that jams up an entire thread at 100% cpu and uses a ton of ram.

Obviously, we need to fix the underlying code, but the problem is that this thread never seems to time out. After 5 minutes by default the client will throw an exception but this does not affect the server.

This particular issue went unnoticed for quite a while, and I'd like to put in a safety net to make sure this doesn't happen again down the line.

I have AOP set up with Unity calling GetNext() to invoke the service, so perhaps I can `Task.Run` this and kill the thread if it takes too long, but could there be a nicer way?

Comment: Ta, looks like there's nothing built in, so the AOP running the service on a thread and terminating it should do the trick. Cheers.

Comment: If you do decide to use the Task.Run approach remember that we have the [Task.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that waits for a task to complete or timeouts, a bit nicer then just killing the task.

Comment: Appreciated, I did not realise that existed! I was using `Task.WhenAny` and specifying the 2nd task as `Thread.Sleep(5000);`! D'oh!